# Do any of the specs increase flamethrower power in BC2: Vietnam?

Tags: battlefield-bad-company-2-vietnam

Do magnum ammo or extra demolition specs make flamethrower stronger in BC2: Vietnam?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, magnum ammo and extra demolition specs don't make flamethrower stronger.